# Add UIButton and UIImage in TableView Section header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I can't figure out what is wrong in this code. i want to display button and image in tableview section header

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView()
         let image = UIImageView()
        image.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width - 10 , y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
        image.image = UIImage.init(named: "triangle.png")
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.origin.x, y: view.frame.origin.y, width: view.frame.width - 30, height: view.frame.height)
        button.setTitle("Open", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .yellow
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonclick), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(image)
        view.addSubview(button)
        return view
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to set view's frame

Comment: What are you returning in heightForHeaderInSection?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR i am returning 50 in heightForHeaderInSection

Comment: give height for header in section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't set imageView and button frame by view frame. Because when `viewForHeaderInSection` function is being called view frame will be 0.

Instead of `view` you can use `tableview`

```
  image.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.width - 20 , y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
  button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width - 30, height: 50)
```

It is recommended to use autolayout instead of setting frame.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code just after initialising `view` :

```
view.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: heightForHeaderInSection)
```

you forgot to set the view's frame.